# Is this a memory failure being logged (CentOS web server)

Tags: centos, memory, kernel, logging

```
$ sudo tail /var/log/messages
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
Jan 30 13:47:58 www kernel: EDAC MC0: CE row 3, channel 0, label "": Corrected error (Socket=0 channel=1 dimm=1)
```

As you can see, this is logging at a phenomenal rate, I don't know about EDAC though. From what I understand this is indicating a faulty stick of RAM possibly, does this seem likely?

I understand this is little to go one, what else can I do to shed some light on this? This is a live server so I can't reboot it or take it down easily bare in mind.

Comment: I have a second problem relating to this one; How can I stop this from being logged 100 times a second? This box is writing about 2MBs of logs a second, which is quite a lot! For the moment I have stopped rsyslogd. Is there another way though as other processes wont be able to log anything now?

Comment: [rsyslog rate limiting](http://rsyslog.com/how-to-use-rate-limiting-in-rsyslog/) might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish my servers' ECC chips were supported by the EDAC code I'm running! Try `dmidecode -t memory` to see the ECC hardware you have.

In your logs you're getting a notification from an ECC chip; If your chip hadn't been supported (like mine!) you'd get silent ECC corrections. In your case, the ECC correction happened **and** you also got notified, because you have support.

I'd go and change that memory stick at first. On the other hand, you might have a faulty channel, or a faulty processor core. I've once diagnosed such a problem  with memtest86.org (the original memtest86 has SMP support, try it memtest86+).

Disable ECC in BIOS, boot memtest86 using a floppy/USB stick, and see if a bunch of addresses get flagged, all in a row: might be a memory channel problem if that happens.

Comment: in my case i use software from the hardware vendor (dell), i use OMSA to diagnostic the hardware issue (memory, etc), no need to reboot to check like memtest, you can check when the server is running.